# MongoDB getting last elements is not working properly with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hello in my project i am aiming a simple task.just retrieve the latest 10 entries from my database.i tried almost every possibility on internet.i even tried from mongo.exe to run the commands but couldnt get any result.need your help here.

**index.js**

```
var messageprocesses = require("./models/messages"); 

   app.get("/messagesreceived",function(req,res){

        var response = {};

        //returns nothing
        messageprocesses.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1,function(err, data){

            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
            }
            res.json(response);
        });

    });
```

At above code i have tried to make my query like these also

```
//gives me toarray is not a function error
messageprocesses.find({}, {limit: 30}).toArray(function(err, docs){})

//brings 10 input but not the latest 10 inputs
messageproceses.find({}, {}, { _id: -1, limit : 10}

//empty find query is working but i need only 10 result
 messageproceses.find({},function(err,docs){})
```

**messages.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase');

var mongoSchema =   mongoose.Schema;

var messages = {
    "chat_id" : String,
    "message" : String,
    "sender" : String,
    "receivers" : String
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('messages',messages);
```

if you need more info i can provide.thanks for cooperation

Comment: How do you insert the data? From mongo reference (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id): `The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation time is not strict within a single second. If multiple systems, or multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values, within a single second; ObjectId values do not represent a strict insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in non-strict ordering even for values because client drivers generate ObjectId values.`

Comment: in my case this explanation is not valid because i am using only one computer and two different browser to test my message ability.so the timestamp and other stuff is generating regularly.i am sure because i have checked them over "mongo.exe" file.

Comment: On what basis do you identify the entries are latest?

Comment: from objectid we can sort them in descending order.so i was using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[`exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec)** method on the query to return the result in the callback:

```
var messageprocesses = require("./models/messages"); 
app.get("/messagesreceived",function(req,res){

    var response = {};

    messageprocesses.find({})
                    .sort({"_id":-1})
                    .limit(10)
                    .exec(function(err, data){

                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
                        } else {
                            console.log(data);
                            response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
                        }
                        res.json(response);
                    });

});
```

---

The other queries you tried did not work because you were using the mongo server methods directly whereas the Mongoose API methods wrap them differently. For example, the query with the [`limit`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) method

```
//gives me toarray is not a function error
messageprocesses.find({}, {limit: 30}).toArray(function(err, docs){})
```

did not work because in Mongoose it does not accept a callback function as a parameter, only numerical values.

The other query

```
//brings 10 input but not the latest 10 inputs
messageproceses.find({}, {}, { _id: -1, limit : 10}
```

did not bring the desired result as you did not specify the **[`sort()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort)** option.

Well, as for this one

```
//empty find query is working but i need only 10 result
messageproceses.find({},function(err,docs){})
```

you also did not specify the **[`sort()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort)** and **[`limit()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit)** methods on the query.

Comment: worked like a charm.thank you man appreciate your help.can i ask something to learn.why the other codes did not work properly?

Comment: @nomad There you go, I've added some explanation for you :)